# Celery: Worker with concurrency and reserved tasks only running 1 task

Tags: concurrency, celery, django-celery

Some of the tasks in my code were taking longer and longer to execute.

Upon inspection I noticed that although I have my worker node set to concurrency 6, and 6 processes exist to 'do work', but only 1 task is shown under 'running tasks'. Here is a little visual proof:

Here are the worker options:

[image: The worker options, as seen by flower]

And here is the task tab for that worker with only 1 running process:

[image]

I have found that if I restart celery, the concurrency is once again respected and i will see >1 running task, but after some amount of time/tasks it reverts back to this behavior..

Any ideas for fixing this intermittent problem?

Comment: I've encountered the same problem on Heroku. During a long running task all other workers don't accept any new tasks. Any luck with this?

Comment: Are you experiencing this bug? https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1845

Comment: Hi Buttons840, I can't be sure after just glancing at that issue, but there seem to be a lot of similar. My team is going to keep an eye on that issue and see if its resolution solves our problems (and if we can avoid using '-Ofair' option). Good find!

Comment: Does anyone know why celery isn't running anything on the other worker(s) on the same box? is it because the main job eats up too much CPU? @steve-gregory

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's your use case, but I ran into similar problems when I had a mix of long and short tasks. Basically what happened is that at some point a process could start a very long running task, while prefetching a few other tasks, preventing them from being consumed by other processes. So I disabled the prefetching stuff, which is useful only if you're running a lot of short tasks.

To disable the prefetch, you need Celery 3.1+ and the [Ofair setting](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefork-pool-prefetch-settings), for instance:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info -Ofair
```

Comment: Even with the prefetching issue, shouldn't new tasks be handled correctly by the other processes since the tasks have not been prefetched?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in answering this question. I am marking this  as the answer because it seems, at least for now, to have fixed the problem. My # of running tasks is closer to the concurrency limit now, but I have yet to try this at a larger scale..

Comment: Wow I am surprised celery pre-fetches tasks... I mean the performance gain from this is marginal compared to the headache is causes when tasks aren't started immediately because they've already been fetched by that particular worker and something executing now is taking some time!!!

Comment: To follow up on this -- the -O Fair option alone did NOT clear my problems up. I have tried setting larger (and smaller) values of Concurrency (on the worker), MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD (on the worker), and CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER all to no avail. Will write a solution if i find one.

Comment: this `-Ofair` option only seems to have fixed my issue; my active tasks converged from 20 to 1 and now (ofc after restart it goes back to normal) it maintains since about 1h at 18-20/20; It's because of the long running tasks as mentioned here. This solution is nice that can be applied only per queue, so I can use this queue with long-running tasks.

Comment: It's hard to believe that the default behavior prevents tasks from running efficiently. At the least, the documentation should be upfront when discussing concurrency, not hidden at the end of the part on optimization... this isn't an optimization, it's a bug fix.

Comment: Does anyone know why celery isn't running anything on the other worker(s) on the same box? is it because the main job eats up too much CPU? @sébastien-deprez

Answer (score 4):

The docs mention [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/optimizing.html#reserve-one-task-at-a-time) how to reserve one task at a time - or only as many as you have concurrency:

> Often users ask if disabling “prefetching of tasks” is possible, but what they really mean by that, is to have a worker only reserve as many tasks as there are worker processes (10 unacknowledged tasks for -c 10)
>
> That’s possible, but not without also enabling late acknowledgment. Using this option over the default behavior means a task that’s already started executing will be retried in the event of a power failure or the worker instance being killed abruptly, so this also means the task must be idempotent
> ...
> You can enable this behavior by using the following configuration options:

```
task_acks_late = True
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
```

or the code equivalent:

```
app = Celery(...)
app.conf.worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
app.conf.task_acks_late = True
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, along with  --concurrency=1 -Ofair worker options, in celery 5.2