# how to configure celery executing tasks concurrently from on queue

Tags: python, concurrency, celery

In an environment with 8 cores, celery should be able to process 8 incoming tasks in parallel by default. But sometimes when new tasks are received celery place them behind a long running process.

I played around with default configuration, letting one worker consume from one queue.

`celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=8`

Is my understanding wrong, that one worker with a concurrency of 8 is able to process 8 tasks from one queue in parallel?

How is the preferred way to setup celery to prevent such behaviour described above?

Comment: I've experienced the same behaviour. While googling around I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519559/celery-worker-with-concurrency-and-reserved-tasks-only-running-1-task) which seems similar. Maybe the solution described there helps?

Comment: I can see how prefetching could cause this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it simply concurrency is the number of jobs running on a worker.  Prefetch is the number of job sitting in a queue on a worker itself.  You have 1 of 2 options here.  The first is to set the prefetch multiplier down to 1.  This will mean the worker will only keep, in your case, 8 additional jobs in it's queue.  The second which I would recommend would be to create 2 different queues one for your short running tasks and another for your long running tasks.

Comment: Would it be able to define more workers consuming from the same queue without processing the same tasks in parallel?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you mean.  You would be able to assign multiple workers to the same queue the would work on tasks at the same time but the will never grab the same task from a queue.

Comment: than, that s a strange behaviour, i recognized when playing around with my celery instance. i am using the same worker command appended by -n worker2.%%h

Comment: The -n option names the worker look into the -Q option and moving your tasks into different queues.