# What happened when celery task code was changed before prefetched task executed?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Does celery detect the changes of task code even if task already is prefetched as past task code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you must reload the workers.

Comment: When I reload the workers, celery worker execute task as latest code even if the task was already prefetched like eta setting?

Comment: Cool. I don't need to care about prefetched task as past code.

Comment: ETA is not related to [prefetch](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits) - also see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040039/understanding-celery-task-prefetching) - you should probably read the celery docs a few times in order to understand basic issues like this.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great Q&A.