# Celery prefetch multiplier setting no effect

Tags: python, celery

I have a series of servers running multiple workers.  These are long-running tasks, requiring anywhere from 10 minutes to 36 hours.  As such, I'd like to avoid prefetching if at all possible and have each worker pick up a singular new task after completing.

I'm using the `celeryd` init.d service, and have

```
CELERYD_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

in `/etc/default/celeryd` of the worker server.

However, if I go to the python shell console and do

```
from work_project.celery import app
inspector = app.control.inspect()
inspector.stats()
```

I get this in the dict output:

```
...
u'prefetch_count': 4,
...
```

I'm using RabbitMQ as the broker and Redis as the backend.  I suspect this prefetching is having the effect of several workers remaining idle after completing their initial task because other workers have pending tasks in their queues.  For example, currently I have two servers with nine workers total running.  At the start of a 20 task batch, all nine were running concurrently.  Now, approximately 90m later, only six workers are active.

Comment: Any updates on this @Jason ..I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I found adding `--maxtasksperchild=1' to the `CELERY_OPTS` parameter in  `/etc/defaults/celeryd` with the goal of having the worker execute one task and then terminating itself did the trick for this particular issue.

Comment: Thanks so much Jason for sharing. One more thing, did more of a googling - This link should help anyone ending up here which solved for me:

[SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040039/understanding-celery-task-prefetching)
and this
[Celery DOCS](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#worker-settings)

Answer (score 2):

I deal with the same problem this way.

Running worker with: `celery worker --prefetch-multiplier=1 --concurrency=1 -Ofair`

Under Django settings: `CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE = True`

```
Django==3.0.2
celery==4.4.0
```

---

It's important to have concurrency=1, because prefetch-multiplier multiplies on concurrency

-Ofair - might be redundant, need to check

Acks late param on worker didn't find (or didn't work) for me

Setting without django need to check (too lazy for it). Might be `CELERYD_TASK_ACKS_LATE = True`

Comment: Do you know what is the reason why it didn't work from celery init?