# Celery prefetching not working celery app argument

Tags: celery, celeryd

I have a long task that I am asynchronously running with celery. Since I am using multiple workers I was getting poor load balancing due to prefetching. I initially tried to turn it off like this

```
# __init__.py 
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery(
                __name__,
                broker=CONFIG['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
                backend=CONFIG['CELERY_BROKER_URL'], 
                worker_prefetch_multiplier=1,
                #task_acks_late=True,
            )
```

```
# celery_runner.py
from server import celery
from server.app import create_app, init_celery
app = create_app()

init_celery(app, celery)
from . import tasks
```

And running my worker using
`celery -A server.celery_runner.celery worker --loglevel=info -c 1 -n w1 -Ofair -E`

But it did not give any result. On searching, I found this S/O post [37351549](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351549/celery-prefetch-multiplier-setting-no-effect) which suggests the command-line option.

On switching to `celery -A server.celery_runner.celery worker --loglevel=info -c 1 -n w1 -Ofair -E  --prefetch-multiplier 1` which worked. Why did it not work through the celery init option?

Answer (score 0):

I have never passed config parameters directly, as arguments to the Celery constructor. Instead I always used the super-useful [config_from_object()](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/application.html#config-from-object) method. I suggest you give it a try.

Comment: I see, I just had the 3 options so I was using init method. It seems weird that this can cause the issue. Will try this

Comment: You can simply use dictionary, and pass it to config_from_object()