# Starting multiple processes in Celery

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a problem with configuring Celery for Django.

This is how I start django-celery:

```
python manage.py celery worker --autoscale=10,2
```

Example of a task:

```
@task
def test(i):
    print "ITERATION {} START".format(i)
    time.sleep(10)
    print "ITERATION {} END".format(i)
    return True
```

And I call this task with:

```
for i in range(10):
    test.delay(i)
```

What I expect to happen is that if I send 10 tasks to queue, 10 processes should open - one for each task.

What actually happens is that the random number of processes are started, usually 4 and **after these 4 tasks are finished**, another 3 start and **after they finish**, another 3 start. This happens even for tasks that take longer to complete, e.g. 2 minutes.

Can someone explain this behavior? How can I start all tasks immediately if autoscale upper limit allows it?

Also, though lower limit in autoscale is 2, when server is started, 3 processes run. Why is that?

Platform: OpenWRT, Dual-Core processor, 2GB RAM.

Comment: You might want to check the concurrency setting in the celery environment to see if that's what's limiting the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Celery by default creates a worker per core, so I am assuming you are running on a machine with 4 cores. You can configure this using the flag `--concurrency` see [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) for further details.

After that you said 3 processes start and then 2 and so on, a task will start only once another has finished, and that also can be delayed sometimes because of the prefetch policy. You can see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040039/understanding-celery-task-prefetching) for more details.

Celery starts a main process and X workers - the main process manages the workers, restarts them when needed and dispatches tasks to the workers. Therefore if you have 2 workers - you will have 3 processes.

Comment: The machine is dual core.

You are right about main process and workers.

Comment: How are you running celery? Give more info. Do you still have open questions? Did I help?